# Passing Params to Another Page Using React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

how can I pass my `type2` params on DoctorCategory to another page? I tried like these below, but it gets an error said `can't find variable: type2`

this `type2` is the value from firebase

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
const [categoryDoctor, setCategoryDoctor] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    Fire.database()
        .ref('category_doctor/')
        .once('value')
        .then(res => {
            console.log('data category: ', res.val())
            if (res.val()) {
                setCategoryDoctor(res.val())
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            showError(err.message)
        })

}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    getData('user').then(res => {
        console.log('data user:', res)
    })
}, [])

return (
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>How can we help you?</Text>
                <View style={styles.category}>
                    <DoctorCategory
                        type1='General'
                        type2={categoryDoctor.categoryA}
                        pic={ILLDocGen}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ChooseDoctor', type2)} //<== this one
                    />
            </View>
        </View>
)}
```

And I call it on another page using.

```
const ChooseDoctor = ({navigation, route}) => {

const type = route.params
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header1 type='light' title= {`Select a ${type.type2}`}/>
    </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `props` in `ChooseDoctor` component! use this:

```
const ChooseDoctor = ({navigation, route, props}) => {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header1 type='light' title= {`Select a ${props.type2}`}/>
    </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd param is an object

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ChooseDoctor',{
   type2
)}
```

Reference https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-nested-navigators